# When i use UserDefaults.standard.object in Alamofire it shows "Extra argument in call" error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, alamofire

When I Use the Alamofire Function With Some CoreData Like `UserDefaulfts.standard.object` then the xcode will Throws an Error `Extra Argument in call` i tried approx all the Ans from Stackoverflow Like `HTTPMethod` and `.JSONEncoding` but not Happening

```
func Sync(){

    let url = "http://abcd.com/reportlist"
    let parameters = ["sort_by":"month_year",
                      "start":"1",
                      "end":"10"]


    let key2 = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "accessToken") 

    let headers = [
        "Authorization": key2,
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"]


    Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
        if response.result.isSuccess
        {

            var dictVal = response.result.value
            let data1 = response.data
            .................
```

Comment: Hi. Do you mind selecting the answer you found helpful?

Answer (score 1):

Hold option key and press `object(forKey` function to read documentation hint. You will see that return type of that function is optional since nothing can be stored under the key you pass, right? So your `key2` constant also is of Optional type.

Then when you use it in dictionary, `headers` itself becomes of type `"String: Optional(String)"` as one of values is Optional (key2).

Alamofire expects `[String: String]` dictionary type in `headers` parameter and since the type of your `headers` dict does not match it generates this error - `extra argument`. Like `I don't know why you pass it to me I do not expect anything of type like that`

That is it

So you either use `string(forKey` method which will return empty string in case nothing is stored under the key passed, or provide default value like that

`let key2 = (UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "accessToken") as? String) ?? "defaultAccessTokenOrNothing"` which has the same result as first suggestion

Answer (score 0):

the Key used here is a String Type and in Header passing, u did not Mention the type of variable in a header

before I used this

`let key2:String = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "accessToken") as! String`

xcode is again Happy to Code...

Comment: if you use `as! String` then the app will crash when "accessToken" doesn't exist. You can use: `as? String ?? ""` (default value) or `guard...` or `if let...` or whatever you want. Only use **!** when you are sure that the value it's not nil.

Comment: Are you aware that there is even `string(forKey`? However it returns an optional, too.